# Is $f(z)=e^z$ is bounded on the imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Is $f(z)=e^z$ bounded on the imaginary axis?

My attempt: I know $f(z) = e^z$ is nonconstant entire function because its derivative

$\frac{\partial e^z}{\partial z} = e^z$ ...

When I take $z = x + iy$ then I got

$f(z) = e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^x \cdot e^{iy} = e^x \cdot (\cos(x) + i \sin(y)) =e^x \cos(x) + i (e^x) \sin(x)$

I know that $e^x$ is unbounded so my answer is that it will unbounded on the imaginary axis.

Is my answer correct or not, please verify my mistakes

Comment: Wrong. Just compute $|e^{it}|$ for $t$ real.

Comment: No. The imaginary axis has $x=0.$ (BTW your last formula must have $y$ as arguments.)

Comment: why u take Modulus  see  my function is f(z)= e^z...there is no modulus@JohnB

Comment: im not getting imaginaryaxis has x=0@ gammatester

Comment: If $z=x+iy$ then $z$ is real if $y=0,$ and $z$ is purely imaginary (is on the imaginary axis) if $x=0$. If you do not understand  this, look at the basics of complex numbers.

Comment: okkk i got it  now ,,,,thanks a lots @gammatester,,,,,actually John B has confused me,,he has take |e^it|...